# WooCommerce, show some message after product were added to cart and update quantity of cart in header

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried to figure this out for 2nd day already, but all I get is one of these two - neither it shows me a "View Cart" message (which I don't know where/how to edit) but only updates cart quantity at the next page refresh, or it refreshes cart quantity after adding item to cart, but doesn't show any message.

To show a message without cart quantity update in `content-product.php` I used this piece of code:

```
<div class="prod-item-add-to-cart">
    <?php

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
        sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>',
                esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
                esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
                esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
                esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
                esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
                esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
            ),
        $product );

        ?>
    </div>
```

And In header I have this:

```
<?php echo sprintf ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?> <?php _e('pcs.', 'eg'); ?> / ~ <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?>
```

To update quantity in header, but in this case added cart message doesn't show, I used this code in `content-product.php`:

```
<div class="prod-item-add-to-cart">
    <?php do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item'); ?>
</div>
```

I need to make both options work - to show some success message after adding item to cart, and to update cart quantity without update.

Answer (score 0):

please check following code for message after added product into the cart.

```
    /**
      * Custom Add To Cart Messages
      * Add this to your theme functions.php file
    **/
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_message', 
          'custom_add_to_cart_message' );
    function custom_add_to_cart_message() {
global $woocommerce;
    // Output success messages
    if (get_option('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add')=='yes') :
        $return_to  = get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('shop'));
        $message    = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button">%s</a> %s', 
        $return_to, __('Continue Shopping &rarr;', 'woocommerce'), __('Product successfully added to your cart.', 'woocommerce') );
     else :
        $message    = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button">%s</a> %s', 
          get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('cart')), __('View 
          Cart &rarr;', 'woocommerce'), __('Product successfully added 
          to your cart.', 'woocommerce') );
     endif;

    return $message;
 }
```

Hope this helps you